# How to avoid opening a new Alert dialog if there is one opened already in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on this fragment where I have two edit texts and when clicked individually opens an alert dialog. I have been facing this issue where, when the edit text is clicked one after another fastly, it opens two alert dialogs one above another. Is there any way I can avoid this.

I've tried using `<item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>` in the `AppTheme` and also used this [solution](https://medium.com/@simonkarmy2004/solving-android-multiple-clicks-problem-kotlin-b99c06135da0) but these solutions solve a different scenario.

Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: ' when the edit text is clicked one after another fastly'. Does it mean when you click on first edit text then click on the second right a way?

Comment: @SonTruong exactly. Even before the first alert dialog is opened, if the second one is clicked i see both the alert dialogs opened.

Comment: You can disable the other one when the first one is clicked.

Comment: simple hack - use a boolean variable like "isAlertDialogPopped" to keep value. Then check this condition before any alert pops. change this value of this varaible when u popped up and close alerts.

Comment: @Lucefer Thank you but I have this solution in mind but wanted to check if there is any other solution as I have many fragments to implement the same one.

Comment: Disable another one when click on the first one is not good solution. I think when users click on the first one, you can set listener on the other to null. And  onDismiss callback of the first one, you set listener on the other to your listener.

Comment: As a result, the UI still not changed, and you do not need to add extra variable to detect whether a dialog is showed or not.

Comment: I think it is better to have the other one not even clickable when the first one is clicked and waiting for the dialog to pop up. If you just remove the listener and allow switching focus to the other field before the dialog of the first field pop up, user may be confused to figure out which field is the current alert dialog corresponding to.

Comment: @RickyMo, In that case, I need to handle the different order of clicks. let's say the user decides to click the second edit text first and not the first one. So I have to see handle this situation as well right as in disabling all other edit texts (which opens alert dialogs) when one edit text is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the other `EditText` after the first one is clicked so that only one of the two can be clicked. Re-enable it when the dialog dismiss.

```
    val input1 : EditText = findViewById(R.id.input1)
    val input2 : EditText = findViewById(R.id.input2)

    input1.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, b ->
        if(b)
        {
            input2.isEnabled = false
            AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("input1").setMessage("input1").setNeutralButton("ok"){ _, _ ->
                input2.isEnabled = true
            }.create().show()
        }
    }
    input2.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, b ->
        if(b)
        {
            input1.isEnabled = false
            AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("input2").setMessage("input2").setNeutralButton("ok"){ _, _ ->
                input1.isEnabled = true
            }.create().show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [solution](https://medium.com/@simonkarmy2004/solving-android-multiple-clicks-problem-kotlin-b99c06135da0) here if you do the following:

- Instead of calling the extension `View.setSafeOnClickListener`, set SafeClickListener to a local field:

  `val safeClickListener = SafeClickListener { view ->
      when(view.id) {
          R.id.input1 -> // onClick event for input1
          R.id.input2 -> // onClick event for input2
      }
  }`
- then set the click listener for those views to use the same instance of SafeClickListener:

  `findViewById<View>(R.id.input1).setOnClickListener(safeClickListener)`
  `findViewById<View>(R.id.input2).setOnClickListener(safeClickListener)`

This way the interval used in `SafeClickListener` will prevent a rapid second click event from happening on either of the Views.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple way in which you can handle this scenario. If you need to keep it clean without involving any boolean variable, then use **isShowing()** method.

you can refer following snippet.

```
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

if (alert.isShowing()) {
    // don't do anything
}
else {
    // show dialog
}
```

Comment: But isn't this method useful when you are opening the same dialog again and again rather than a different dialog?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `isShowing()` method

```
  AlertDialog yourAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();

    if(!yourAlertDialog.isShowing()){
        //Here you can show your dialog else not       
        yourAlertDialog.show()
    }
```

IN KOTLIN

```
 val alertDialog= activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it).create() };

        if(!alertDialog?.isShowing!!){
            //Here you can show your dialog else not       
            alertDialog.show()
        }
```

InCase you have two or more dialogs ,

```
  val alertDialog1= activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it).create() };
     val alertDialog2= activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it).create() };
     val alertDialog3= activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it).create() };

 if(alertDialog1?.isShowing!! && alertDialog1?.isShowing!!){
               //Some dialog is shown
            }else{
               //Here you can show your dialog else not       
                alertDialog3.show()
              }
```

Comment: But isn't this method useful when you are opening the same dialog again and again rather than a different dialog?

Comment: are you having multiple dialog ?

Comment: then you need to add check for all those alertdialogs , like 

if(alertDialog1.isShowing || alertDialog2.isShowing){//Some dialog is shown}else{do something here}